# filter all the installed apps with their model and permission in django

Tags: django, permissions

I want to display list of all the installed app and model as well as their permission.

for example

```
app_name_1
   model_name_1
     permission_1
     permission_2
     ...........
   model_name_2
     permission_1
     permission_2
     ...........
app_name_2
   model_name_1
     permission_1
     permission_2
     ...........
   model_name_2
     permission_1
     permission_2
     ...........
and so on.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of installed apps (excluding Django defaults):

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

apps_list = [app for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS if not 'django' in app]
```

then get all models:

```
models = []
for app in apps_list:
    models.append(apps.all_models[app])
```

next is actually getting the permissions:

```
for model in models:
    app_lbl = model._meta.app_label
    model_name = model._meta.model_name
    permissions = Permission.objects.filter(content_type__app_label=app_lbl, content_type__model=model_name)
```